# MS Visual Studio - how to import a project or solution from file system and know what kind of project it is

Tags: c#, visual-studio

first, I'm new to C# and MS IDE Visual Studio. 
I develop in Java and use JBoss Dev Studio, open source, maven builds , etc...
I'm learning VS IDE and C# now.

I've been given code for a MS .Net C# application, a fellow left the company and I now need to take it over.  It doesn't perform all it needs to do, and I need to determine the inbound and outbound data formats.  however, I can't tell what kind of project this is or how to import it from file system or what to look for to tell what it is? I hope this makes sense.

the code was given to me as files in file system copy. 
I'm not sure what options to select to import it?
is there any certain file names I can look for to tell what kind of solution/project this code is? .NET Web, .NET core, ...

I'm a bit confused.

the file system has 3 folders, a docs, publish, and src folder. most all folders under publish are empty,

SRC - has Apps, Core, Domain, Resources, Services and Testing... however, most of these are empty also?

1. how to tell what kind of project I have
2. how to import a project or solution from file system.

I feel I'm making it more difficult than needs to be. 
thank you!

Comment: A project can be a combination of different classes and you can hybrid projects that contain more than one type.  A project can just be a Class Project which can b e used by other projects.  So there is no real answer.  c# requires a Main() to run directly from windows so usually the class type where main is located would be the Kind of project, but there is no real rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the filesystem structure you mention sounds like a universal convention for organizing the files, so we really can't help you there. Aside from asking someone who organized or worked on the code previously, the best shot is to open solutions and projects and see what they reference.

Look for files with the `.sln` extension; this loads a *solution* into Visual Studio. A solution consists of multiple projects with an extension in the pattern `.*proj`, usually `.csproj` (C#), `.vbproj` (Visual Basic .NET), or `.fsproj` (F#). Each project produces one output *assembly* file (`.dll` or `.exe`), so a solution file is used to coordinate development among multiple outputs.

Comment: thank you Joe.  Joe, shouldn't I be able to build this now in VS.NET ?  I found the .sln, and a handful of csproj files. however, I cannot build the code, many errors.  Silly question, is there something special I need to do? resources or assemblies ?  thanks again.

Comment: why does the "Solution Explorer" show 47 of 48 projects ? as there is something missing ?

Comment: @GLMills Ordinarily the solution should be build-able once you have the solution, so I can't really help with the problem with the information given.